# Please explain why does script works this way

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am working in PostgreSQL, and I have just started learning about simultaneously working transactions.
My problem is when I run the whole script, I get the same transaction id.
The first tuple should have 1 id and second 2 should have the same id.

When I run the script in lines (one by one) I get the correct result.
Why does it work this way?

```sql
DELETE FROM test;
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'A');
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 'B');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 'C');
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've touched Postgres, so maybe I'm missing something here, but can you explain in more detail where you get what id and what you'd have expected instead?

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit more, are you getting any error? What are your results and your expected results?

Comment: What do you mean with "transaction ID"?

Comment: Simple - you're running all those lines in a single transaction. Assuming you're using PGAdmin, if you first highlight and execute ONLY the first INSERT, then hilight/execute the rest, then check (xmin), you'll see a different transaction id between them. Selecting the whole block executes it all in one transaction. Putting a new BEGIN TRANSACTION in the middle of an existing transaction will not start a new one.

Comment: By transaction ID I ment xmin attribute of transaction, which is ID of transaction that created tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That block of code is being executed in a single transaction. You haven't said how it's being executed, but if you stick it in pgadmin and run it all together, or put it in a file and call it with psql, a transaction will be automatically started and committed at the end. The `BEGIN TRANSACTION` line doesn't start a new transaction because a transaction is already open. That's why executing it all together will create rows with the same transaction ids.

To demonstrate, run this line by line:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'A');
SELECT txid_current();
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 'B');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 'C');
SELECT txid_current();
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

You'll see each `SELECT` returns the same id. You'll also see a message on the second `BEGIN` which states a transaction is already in progress.

But if you highlight (in pgadmin) just the first `INSERT` and execute it (without manually doing a `BEGIN`), that's the only line being executed in that automatic transaction. Then the rest gets executed in a second transaction, whether you execute it one line at a time or all together, because the transaction is being handled manually.

Now if you run these lines all together:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'A');
COMMIT;
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 'B');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 'C');
COMMIT;
```

And then run this:

```
SELECT xmin, *
FROM test
```

You'll see the transaction numbers are as expected, because now the transactions are being wholly controlled manually - one created for the first statement, and the second for the other two.